# Handle external WCF Service calling internal WCF Service (auth - session)

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, session, authentication

i need to build this architecture and i need some orientation on "how should i build". I've read many docs and examples but i can't find and figure how to do trying to be efficient and secure:

- External app (android app, ios app) where users, after a login, can access to their personal info and manage the account (updating personal data, showing personal documents related to their account and much more). The username / pwd input must be done only 1 time.
- A public wcf service will receive their actions and will call to a another internal wcf service. It will work like a 'bridge'.
- The internal wcf service will get the request and do the operations needed (logical and db operations). This will return data to the external wcf service and this one to the client (obvious).
- UserName/PWD are stored in a database.
- WCF services can only be accessed with the correct credentials and are IIS hosted.

So i find many problems/questions:

- I don't know HOW and WHERE should I build the AUTH (internal, external, both?).  How can i manage a session between wcf services and app clients to avoid sending credentials every time?
- The client app needs to send credentials every time? This means every service requires to SELECT the database for checking the username?
- SOAP? Rest Services? It doesn't care? (on internal wcf, external wcf, both?).
- I need work with asp.NET sessions or i really don't need? I don't see how services that needs username/pwd that are called frequently and repeatedly are efficient without old asp.net sessions.

Thanks for your help and orientation.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone interested... seems [Routing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) seems to fit for my design and can solve my problem after some tests i have done.